# ChartFX 4.0 components in Delphi XE4: inconsistent design time license issue

Tags: delphi, chartfx

We have a huge app that uses ChartFX 4.0 a lot and we're migrating from Delphi6 to XE4. The programmer mainly responsible so far has basically created a new package for the ChartFX components and has successfully installed it on his machine, and has tested a lot of the code that uses these components. Every thing looked great at this point. Then he tried rebuilding/installing/testing on a couple of other machines - XE4 throws a designtime license not found error when he opens a new project and tries to place a chart object on the form. All machines have a licensed copy of chartFX 4.0 installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate and transfer the `CFX*.lic` file (it's the development license for the `.OCX` file). In Delphi 7, it's `CFX32.lic`, and it's located in the `%WINDIR%\System32` folder.

Comment: This file exists on all the machines and is identical.

Comment: We've had problems like this before due to devs running as admin in XP and therefore missing behaviors that happen in end-user environments, but all three of these machines are Win7 x64 - not sure if that simplifies or complicates things.

Comment: Then it's possible it's not where the .OCX expects it to be and it's not finding it. I only have ChartFX available in D7 running in a WinXP virtual machine, but if I rename that CFX32.lic file or move it from the `System32` folder I can produce the same error you're having. Putting it back there causes the error to go away.